# Calculate relative errors in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there an easy way to calculate errors in Postgres given a table that looks something like this:

```
id | bool  | score
1  | False | 9
1  | True  | 9.6
2  | False | 5
2  | True  | 4.7
```

The output that I want id | (False_row - True_row)/True_row:

```
id | err
1  | -0.0625
2  | 0.063829
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id,
    (false_row - true_row) / true_row
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN bool THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS true_row,
        SUM(CASE WHEN NOT bool THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS false_row
    FROM
        table_name
    GROUP BY
        id
) AS sub;
```

In the subquery (`sub`) take the `true_row` and the `false_row`. This can be done using a variety of aggregate functions, `SUM` for example.

When you have your `true_row` and `false_row` just do the calculations in the outer query.